# Is asking for a general investment strategy profitability on-topic?

Tags: support, questions

> Requests for specific investment buy/sell advice; e.g. "should I sell X?" or "should I buy Y?" or "will X continue to go up?"

Is the question about, whether it is worth to buy Internet ads for a crowdfunding campaign, on topic? It is not about a *specific* investment, but more about personal crowdfunding in general.

Comment: Are you talking about buying ads to promote a crowdfunding campaign for your business plan?

Comment: @BenMiller I have 14 campaigns for noncommercial projects and 1 for a commercial project. Certainly I am going to promote one of the noncommercials

Comment: Considering SE is not a personal advice site, will the question be useful for others and future readers? That's one of the important thing to have in mind before asking on SE. If you can generalize it, then *maybe* it is okay, but still it depends on the site's scope.